# Get url argument to process generic views

Tags: html, django, django-generic-views

I would like to write a one-template view, which depending on the url path will show different field of the model. So for instance if path is

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/trip/2/1/
```

I will get second trip from my db (that works), and `1` should give (as html is written) a description field. I don't know how to process this to `context_processor` in my view. Do you have any ideas?

views.py

```
class TripDescriptionCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):

    model = Trip
    template_name = 'tripplanner/trip_arguments.html'
    fields = ["description", "city", "country", "climate", "currency", "food", "cost", "comment", "accomodation",
    "car", "flight", "visa", "insurance", "remarks"]
    context_object_name = 'trips'
    success_url = '/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

trip_arguments.html

```
 <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">{{ trips.tripName }}</legend>
                    {% if field_id == 1 %}
                        {{ form.description|as_crispy_field }}
                    {% elif field_id == 2 %}
                        {{ form.city|as_crispy_field }}
                    {% endif %}
            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Update</button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

urls.py

```
path('trip/<int:pk>/<int:field_id>', TripDescriptionCreate.as_view(), name='trip-fullfill'),
```

Comment: Well, that should work - the URL kwargs are passed into the template context. The only issue here is that they will be strings, so your conditions should be eg `if field_id == '1'`.

Comment: The page is loading, but it doesn't show the form. When I write something under `{{ form.description|as_crispy_field }}` it also doesn't appear, which means `if` function is not executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I came up with this idea. In my html I added these lines:

```
{% url 'trip-fullfill-description' pk=trip.pk as description_url %}
                {% url 'trip-fullfill-city' pk=trip.pk as city_url %}

{% if request.get_full_path == description_url %}
                    {{ form.description|as_crispy_field }}
                {% elif request.get_full_path == city_url %}
                    {{ form.city|as_crispy_field }}
```